# limit of characters in columns in a table vs. validations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, limit, varchar

I'm a Rails beginner and wanted to ask this question:

How is setting a limit in characters in a name column `(t.string :name, :limit => 5)` in a table diferrent from a validation `validates_length_of :name, :is => 5`?

The first one does not really work when I use it. Even if I put a limit of 5, every time I would save a record with a name of more than 5 characters it would still save it. What is its real use?

The validation is what's working in terms of limiting the characters for a person's name when saving a record.

Am I confusing setting a limit of characters in a table for restricting the number of characters someone can enter into the database?

Answer (score 4):

```
t.string :name, :limit => 5
```

> does not really work when I use it.

This is you main problem. This **does** work as you would expect. Your doing something wrong. I just did the following steps; follow along to make sure you aren't missing something

```
rails g migration CreateFoos my_string:string
# open up the migration file and change it to this

class CreateFoos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :foos do |t|
      t.string :my_string, limit: 5
    end
  end
end
```

create `Foo` file with the following info

```
# app/models/foo.rb
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

and now run your migrations and test

```
rake db:migrate
rails c
Foo.create(my_string: '12345')
Foo.create(my_string: '123456')
```

That last line should throw an error (I'm using postgresql). And if not at the very least `Foo.count` should only return 1

Comment: I finally found out why. I am using sqlite and I did not know that there are no limits in sqlite. Just read from numerous articles. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how you got succeed on this:

```
t.string :name, :limit => 5
```

It should **limit** the characters up to 5.
Otherwise it will result to ActiveRecord error.

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Data too long for column 'name'
```

This one code in Model, will validates length of string/character before save to DB.

```
validates_length_of :name, :is => 5
```

Comment: Yup on the model level I can set limit thru validates. Finally found out that there are no varchar limit in sqlite even if you set one up. Thanks for the answer anyway!